# I need a Google Script to run in a google sheet to delete cells to the right of blank cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need a script to clear the content in cells to the right of blank cells. So if A2 is blank, delete content in B2. I need to do this across about 100 sets of two columns.

I have conditional formatting checkboxes in cells and don't need them when the cell to the left is blank. It's slowing down load time.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like this:

```
//Set data in column B to blank if column A is blank in that row
function clearRows() {
  //First get the data
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();

  //now loop through each row
  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i){
    //if comlun A is blank
    if(data[i][0] == ""){
      //Then set column B to blank
      data[i][1] = "";
    }

  }
  //Save the new data to the sheet
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Peter! This didn't work, so I'll provide some more info. Here is the sheet I'm working with: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bzME1Arpa8Csu5lCI4P2ORh9SIpGI9XmMULH9fWJoDA/edit#gid=1566956467 . For S3 through CT516, I want to identify the "occupations" columns that are blank, and if so, remove the checkbox data validation and empty the adjacent cell. I hope this helps and appreciate any additional guidance!